# Given a list of dictionaries, how can I find how many dictionaries each key appears in?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of `dictionaries` and every `dictionary` has the word as key, and the number of times that word appears in a particular document as value. Now I am wondering How can I find how many `dictionaries` a particular word appears in?

suppose I have a list of following dictionaries:

```
dict1 = {'Association':5, 'Rule':2, 'Mining':3}
dict2 = {'Rule':4, 'Mining':1}
dict3 = {'Association':4, 'Mining':3}
```

Result after counting how many dictionaries a word appears in:

```
result_dict = {'Association':2, 'Rule':2, 'Mining':3}
```

Comment: Can you give some examples? And show what have you tried?

Comment: Dear @ngShravil.py I have edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be easily done with dict comprehension.
First, make a list out of your dicts:

```
dict1 = {'Association':5,'Rule':2,'Mining':3}
dict2 = {'Rule':4,'Mining':1}
dict3 = {'Association':4,'Mining':3}

dicts = [dict1, dict2, dict3]
```

Then, make a set of all the words in the dictionaries with a union (might be a cleaner way to do this, but this worked):

```
all_words = set().union(*[d.keys() for d in dicts])
```

Then, count how many dictionaries each word appears in:

```
{k: sum([1 for d in dicts if k in d.keys()]) for k in all_words}
```

This returned the desired output from your example.

Comment: @JawadTariq, Itamar's reply for your case-insensitivity question is basically to replace `for k in all_words` with `for k in map(str.lower, all_words)`. In the future, please comment on the answer you're referring to, not on another answer. And please ask new questions separately, especially if you've already accepted an answer.

Comment: Thankyou @Eliadl. I will take care of it next time.

Answer (score 2):

[**`Counter`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) is a `dict` subclass that can be useful here:

```
from collections import Counter


dicts = [dict1, dict2, dict3]

key_counters = [Counter(dictionary.keys()) for dictionary in dicts]
start_counter = Counter()

result_dict = sum(key_counters, start_counter)

assert result_dict == {'Association': 2, 'Rule': 2, 'Mining': 3}
```

Comment: This is a better answer than mine, and should be accepted.

Comment: @ItamarMushkin how I can ignore case sensitivity. Association and association are being treated differently.

Comment: Edited my answer to include case-insensitivity. In the future, please comment on the answer you're referring to, not on another answer.

Comment: Itamar thanks. @JawadTariq please ask new questions separately, especially if you've already accepted an answer.

Comment: @JawadTariq For the sake of completeness, case insensitivity can be achieved here too similarly, by replacing `dictionary.keys()` with `key.lower() for key in dictionary.keys()`.